# Add more rooms to chat

Tags: support, status-bydesign, chat

Can more rooms be added to the chat covering more concentrated topics for us to talk about?

Comment: I'm not sure the edits to this question were correct.  Jeff's edit and answer -- and Michael's subsequent edit -- assumed the OP was asking about chat.  But as a 1-rep user, the OP shouldn't have been able to talk in chat.  I usually edit aggressively to fix spelling and grammar issues, but in this case the original post was incomprehensible to me, so I voted to close as noise instead.

Comment: @Popular Oh, I assumed it was about chat because it had the chat tag; I completely missed that that wasn't in the original post. It's probably requesting adding more SO-type sites on other topics, which is covered by [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposals

Answer (score 2):

Any user can create a chat room on a topic (assuming you have the 20 parent site rep).

If you want more rooms on narrower (or just different) topics, create them yourself!

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ:

> Creating a new room requires 100
>   reputation; creating a room where only
>   named users can talk requires 1000
>   reputation.

If you're nice you might succeed in getting someone with > 100 rep. to do it for you though (talking from experience).